# Face Recognition steps: Project Test Image

Tags: c++, opencv

I've some issue with the understanding of the eigenface recognition steps, I've read somewhere that we must project the test image into the eigenspace, and then calculate the distance between the projected image test and the stored projection vectors.

```
// READ THE STORED LEARN DATA
FileStorage fs("test.xml", FileStorage::READ);
Mat stored_mean, stored_eigenvalues, stored_vectors, stored_projections, stored_labels;
int stored_num_componants = fs["num_components"];
fs["mean"] >> stored_mean;
fs["eigenvalues"] >> stored_eigenvalues;
fs["eigenvectors"] >> stored_vectors;
fs["projections"] >> stored_projections;
fs["labels"] >> stored_labels;

// PROJECT THE TEST IMAGE
Mat result;
pca.project(testImageInGrayScale, result); // bugs here ...

// PRINT THE DISTANCES
for (int i = 0; stored_projections.rows; ++i){
    qDebug() << norm( stored_projections.row(i),weightVect );
}
```

the error code is:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (mean.data && eigenvectors.data &&
>   ((mean.rows == 1 && mean.cols == data.cols) || (mean.cols == 1 &&
>   mean.rows == data.rows))) in project, file
>   c:/opencv/sources/modules/core/src/matmul.cpp, line 3042

am I totaly wrong ? or I've just used a wrong method and the wrong types ?

Comment: It's not a question about the type you used, but the way your data is formatted. Look at the error message: do you have data into the mean variable, does mean's rows equal to 1, and so on. A few breakpoints here and there and you will know what's going on. Example here will probably help https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/pca.cpp

Answer (score 0):

Go through [this chapter on "Face Recognition"](http://fivedots.coe.psu.ac.th/~ad/jg/nui08/).

Comment: @awesomeyi will care about it next time onwards